My NGINX-powered website is returning the closed connection message for no apparent reason
So I have just configured a Linux server.
Is there any valid reason as to why I'm seeing the message:

It looks like example.com closed the connection

  #nginx.conf
  user root;
  worker_processes auto;
  pid /run/nginx.pid;
  include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

  events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
  }

 http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
 }

#gunicorn.conf
[program:gunicorn]                                                                                   
directory=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/xxxxx
command=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 
unix:/home/ubuntu/.ssh/xxxxx/app.sock 
xxxxx.wsgi:application  
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log

[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn


#django.conf
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.combined.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.com.key;

# Additional SSL configuration
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/.ssh/xyz/app.sock;
}

# Serving media files
location /assets/images/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/.ssh/xyz/assets/images/;
    autoindex on;
}

# Redirect www to non-www
if ($host = 'www.exampl.com') {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name xyz.com www.example.com;

# Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

The Gunicorn status is RUNNING, so all good there, plus the http redirect to https is working perfectly, but I fail to see why it's closed the connection. What's worse is that for some reason, no error logs are being written in the server despite having this set up correctly. (Why is that?) There is not even any console logs in the browser.
Running the

sudo nginx -t

returns "success" and have restarted nginx as well,
Its actually a ridiculous situation.

Are you sure the requests reach the server?

It should be, the http redirects are working so its reading from the server.

Have... you verified the assumption?

So how do you confirm the request has reached the server?

Check the logs. If it doesn't show up there, verify with wireshark.
